# Serializing a list of system.drawing.image with tag filled

Tags: .net, serialization

- Create new system.drawing.image
- Set image.tag with value
- Add image to imagelist

  ImageList = New List(Of System.Drawing.Image)

  ```
  Using stream As IO.FileStream = File.Open(ThumbFilePath, IO.FileMode.Create)
  Dim formatter As New Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter
  formatter.Serialize(stream, ImageList)
  stream.Flush()
  stream.Close()
  End Using
  ```

So when I retrieve the imagelist from stream and deserialise, the image.tag is nothing. I think the tag isn't even serialized at all.
Is there a way I can save the tag information with each image in the list and serialize it to retrieve it afterwards?

Comment: Why don't you *save* the images in one of the supported formats? Trying to serialize the images, especially using `BinaryFormatter`, doesn't make any sense. No other application will be able to understand this. *.NET itself* won't be able to read this

Comment: Certain image formats have extra metadata and tags. Use an appropriate format instead of trying to "hack" it by serilalizing the abstract `Image` class

Comment: I use this to make a thumbfile list for documents. Sometimes 1 page, sometimes 100s of pages. I wanted to store all thumbs in 1 file. That is why I did this 'solution' so I have only 1 file to read with all thumbs in it. 
It works in .Net, I can see all thumbs after deserialising, but not the tags. And that was my question. Not if my solution was the right one, but if tags can be serialized ;) .

Comment: the solution is the wrong one, which is why no tags can be serialized. Image is an *abstract* class. The `Tag` property is a leftover from VB6 used to store "something" that may be useful to the UI. It's not part of the image itself. If you check [the property docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.tag?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Drawing_Image_Tag) you'll see it's converted to a string during serialization. If you store anything that *can't* be converted to a string, you won't get it back. Finally, BinaryFormatter is very fragile and unsafe

Comment: There are proper ways to store thumbnails and properties. Some formats can have multiple pages, ex TIFF. Other formats can store EXIF tags, like JPG and TIFF. In web development, multiple images are combined in one big image and an offset is used to display one of the images stored in the big image

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was my first attempt with such a thing and had no experience with it at all. I learn the hard way ^^ ...

Answer (score 0):

Deserialisation:

```
Using stream As IO.FileStream = IO.File.Open(ThumbFilePath, IO.FileMode.Open, IO.FileAccess.Read)
            Dim formatter As New Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter
            ImageList = CType(formatter.Deserialize(stream), List(Of System.Drawing.Image))
        End Using
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please use the *Post answer* button only for actual answers. You should modify your original question to add additional information.